# Using if to echo statements based on radio button AND drop down list choices PHP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, radiobuttonlist

I've looked all over the internet for an answer to this specific question but can't seem to find one. Basically, I've got a set of radio buttons and a drop down list that you can choose options from.

```
<form method="get" action="phpindex.php">
    <select name="season">
        <option value="">- Season -</option>
        <option value="spring">Spring</option>
        <option value="summer">Summer</option>
        <option value="fall">Fall</option>
        <option value="winter">Winter</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="beer" value="heavy"/>Heavy
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="beer" value="light"/>Light
    <br />
    <input type="submit" OnClick="show_alert"/>
</form>
```

Based on the combination of your choices, you get a specific statement to echo upon clicking the submit button. For example, if you choose spring as the season, and a heavy beer, a statement should be echoed based upon those choices. The problem is, the echo functions aren't working and I think it's because of the combination of radio buttons and drop down list. Here is my PHP and aforementioned echo functions that aren't working.

```
<?php

$beer = $_GET["beer"];
$season = $_GET["season"];
$spring = $_GET["sp"];
$summer = $_GET["summer"];
$fall = $_GET["fall"];
$winter = $_GET["winter"];
$heavy = $_GET["heavy"];
$light = $_GET["light"];


if ( in_array("spring", $season) && in_array("heavy", $beer)  ) {
echo "$state Bud"; } 
if ( in_array("spring", $season) && in_array("light", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Abita"; }
if ( in_array("summer", $season) && in_array("heavy", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Yuengling"; }
if ( in_array("summer", $season) && in_array("light", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Coors"; }
if ( in_array("fall", $season) && in_array("heavy", $beer) ) {
echo "$state PBR"; }
if ( in_array("fall", $season) && in_array("light", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Miller"; }
if ( in_array("winter", $season) && in_array("heavy", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Natty"; }
if ( in_array("summer", $season) && in_array("light", $beer) ) {
echo "$state Kona"; }

$state = "Well, it looks like it's $season, and you want a $beer beer, so try this brew out:";


?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `in_array()` is for checking whether an *array* contains a value. The `$_GET` parameters aren't arrays, though. A simple `==` should suffice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$_GET` elements used in this way can only be simple data types, not arrays, because each segment of the query string (e.g. `q=v`) is defined to represent a single value `v` -- with key `q` in the `$_GET` array.

As pointed out below, there is an exception to this when `"array[]"` is used for the `name` attribute of the `input` tag which, in this specific case, creates an array in `$_GET`/`$_POST`.

In your case, you want to test against the values directly as strings:

`if ($season == "spring" && $beer == "heavy")`

for example.

Comment: Elements like `<input name="array[]" />` would produce arrays in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: @LinusKleen Oh right, thanks, you learn something new everyday. Although that's one obscure feature (or, at least, I've never crossed paths with it after 6 years of semi-regular PHP development!) and I probably won't be rushing out to use it.

Comment: Harsh downvoting. Edited my answer to reflect the state of things as I understand them now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to save that string to $state above the if statements.

```
$state = .......

if....
if....
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to firstly have the $state = '...' and then your if statements

The $_GET is an array so you can do in_array, but the $_GET['beer'] or $_GET['season'] is NOT an array.

So the $beer and $season is not an array in your case. You can easily change your statements to:

```
$state = "Well, it looks like it's $season, and you want a $beer beer, so try this brew out:";
if ( $season == "spring" && $beer == "heavy"  ) {
    echo "$state Bud"; 
} 
....
```

and so on...

and because I suppose you are expecting just a copy-paste well have there you go:

```
<?php

$beer = $_GET["beer"];
$season = $_GET["season"];
$spring = $_GET["sp"];
$summer = $_GET["summer"];
$fall = $_GET["fall"];
$winter = $_GET["winter"];
$heavy = $_GET["heavy"];
$light = $_GET["light"];

$state = "Well, it looks like it's $season, and you want a $beer beer, so try this brew out:";

if ( $season == "spring" && $beer == "heavy" ) {
    echo "$state Bud"; 
} 
if ( $season == "spring" && $beer == "light" ) {
    echo "$state Abita"; 
}
if ( $season == "summer" && $beer == "heavy" ) {
    echo "$state Yuengling"; 
}
if ( $season == "summer" && $beer == "light" ) {
    echo "$state Coors"; 
}
if ( $season == "fall" && $beer == "heavy" ) {
    echo "$state PBR";
}
if ( $season == "fall" && $beer == "light" ) {
    echo "$state Miller"; 
}
if ( $season == "winter" && $beer == "heavy" ) {
    echo "$state Natty"; 
}
if ( $season == "summer" && $beer == "light" ) {
    echo "$state Kona"; 
}
```

Comment: Ahh, much simpler than I thought! I'm new to this so still learning the ropes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha, I wouldn't have minded making the changes myself, but thanks! Didn't realize how minor the changes needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

THere a few mistake in there

First off, all you need is:

```
$beer = $_GET["beer"];
$season = $_GET["season"];
```

Fall, spring, etc are value, not GET arguments.
After that you check the value of your GET to store the beer anme in a var;

```
if ($beer == 'heavy' && $season == 'spring') $brand= "Bud";
 if ($beer == 'light' && $season == 'spring') $brand= "Abita";
 //ad so on....

$state = "Well, it looks like it's $season, and you want a $beer beer, so try this brew out: $brand";
echo $state;
```

you cannot echo $state, beacuse $state is defined AFTER your echo call.
Instead, simply put the brew in a var, and append it to your state string after all the if.

cheers.